# Problemas para deletar com ajax no laravel 5.3

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Controller

```
public function deletar($id)
  {
    $dado = Todo::find($id)->delete();
     return response()->json($dado);
  }
```

Route

```
 Route::get('/deletar/{id}',['as'=>'todo.deletar',
    'uses'=>'Site\TaskController@deletar']);
```

View
(na minha view estou fazendo uma listagem  de tarefas e nessas tarefas tem botão para deletar a tarefa.Mais é ai que se encontra o problema, na hora de excluir invés de excluir tarefa escolhida exclui sempre a ultima tarefa incluída, ao ver código fonte da pagina msm dando um f5 na pagina, a url no ajax aparece ultima tarefa incluída exemplo: url:"http://127.0.0.1:8000/deletar/71")

```
@extends('layout.site')

@section('titulo','Home')

@section('conteudo')
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col l6 m4">
            @foreach($list as $lists)
            <div class="card black darken-1">
                <div class="card-content white-text">
                    <h4>{{$lists->titulo}}</h4>
                    <p>{{$lists->texto}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-action">
                    <a class="btn deep-orange"
                     href="{{route('todo.editar', $lists->id)}}">Editar</a>

                    <a class="btn deep-orange"  type="submit"

                     name="DelTarefa">Deletar</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
@endsection
@section('script')

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $(function(){
        $('a[name="DelTarefa"]').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url:"{{route('todo.deletar', $lists->id)}}",
                type: "get",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response)
                {
                    if(response.success)
                    {
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                console.log(response);
                }

            });
        });
    });
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1):

tente algo assim:

```
<div class="container">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col l6 m4">
        @foreach($list as $lists)
        <div id="todo-{{ $lists->id  }}"class="card black darken-1">
            <div class="card-content white-text">
                <h4>{{$lists->titulo}}</h4>
                <p>{{$lists->texto}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action">
                <a class="btn deep-orange"
                 href="{{route('todo.editar', $lists->id)}}">Editar</a>

                <a class="btn deep-orange" href="javascript:del({{ $lists->id }});">Deletar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function del(value) {

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",

            data: {"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}","id": value},

            url: "{{ route('todo.deletar') }}",

            success: function(msg){

                console.log('Ok deletou')
               $("#todo"+value).hide('slow');

            }
        });

    }

</script>
```

Altere sua rota para somente post sem necessidade da variável ok

Em seu Controller:

```
    public function deletar(Request $request)
  {

    $id = $request->input('id'); 

    $dado = Todo::find($id)->delete();
     return response()->json($dado);
  }
```

Comment: valeu funcionou, mais porque vc passou tolken aqui ?                 `data: {"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}","id": value} `  . So usar ajaxSetup passando csrf não  e suficiente?

Comment: Olá amigo, fico feliz de ter dado certo. Gosto de usar o envio do token dessa maneira pois economiza código e erros!! Abraço !!!